# JavaScript string into multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm passing myself a string of results from php by ajax that I would like to put into a two dimensional array in JavaScript

The string looks like:       value1^*value2^*value3^*value4***value1^*value2^*value3^*value4

I would like to split the values by '^*' into the first row of the dimensional array, then the next row would be after the '***'

Desired array: 
`var Text = [['value1', 'value2','value3','value4'],[value1','value2','value3','value4']];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split your string into an array of strings ( `value1^*value2^*value3^*value4` and `value1^*value2^*value3^*value4` ), after that you will need [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to creates a new arrays inside each array which we get before.

Example:

```js
var str = "value1^*value2^*value3^*value4***value1^*value2^*value3^*value4"

str = str.split('***')

str = str.map((value) => value.split('^*'))

console.log(str)
```

Comment: You beat me to it! This is perfect.

Comment: How about an explanation so that the OP understands what's going on?

Comment: It would be less confusing to use "value" or currentValue (mdn) instead of "index" in the argument name, since it's not the array index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```js
var input = "value1^*value2^*value3^*value4***value5^*value6^*value7^*value8";

 var res = input.split('***').map(function(rowValues){
 return rowValues.split('^*');
})

console.log(res);
```